# Execute service or any function when state is actived

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    $stateProvider.state('blogPost', {
      url: '/post/:id',
      templateUrl: 'blogpost.html',
        controller : function($scope, $stateParams){
            $scope.postId = $stateParams.id;
      }
    })
```

I had a service which will fetch the blog content base on $stateParams.id, but how to execute that service only when the user reached the blogPost page? About is my state of the blogPost. I know I cannot call my service in that state because I can't inject that in my config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data comes as a promise from a http call. Which means that you should use the `resolve` property.

```
$stateProvider.state('blogPost', {
  url: '/post/:id',
  templateUrl: 'blogpost.html',
  controller : function($scope, $stateParams, blogposts){
      $scope.blogposts = blogposts;
  },
  resolve: {
      blogposts: function(yourBlogDataService, $stateParams) {
          return yourBlogDataService.getBlogPosts($stateParams.id)
      }
  }
})
```

As you can see you know just inject the blogpost object as parameter into your controller:

```
  controller : function($scope, $stateParams, blogposts){
      $scope.blogposts = blogposts;
  }
```

Comment: then how should I use the blogposts property?